# get view of another application (root)

Tags: android, linux, root

Is it possible to get an instance of a `View` which is not part of the application? as far as I know each application runs under its own `JVM`.

The `Android JUnit test`, which  is infact another application ,some how manages to access the `UI`. Maybe code injection into the `main looper` of the other application. (the question related to rooted devices only)

Comment: "The Android JUnit test, which is infact another application ,some how manages to access the UI" -- that is because the instrumentation framework runs the JUnit tests and the application being tested in a single VM in a single process.